# Google Cloud how to get ID Token by Service Account using php

Tags: php, google-cloud-functions, google-authentication

I created a Service Account, created key for it and stored as JSON file (which includes `roles/cloudfunctions.invoker` role), saved on local.
And have some code which is trying to call Cloud Functions on GCP.

I tested successfully to call my Function on local via `curl`

```sh
curl -X POST  -H "Authorization: bearer $(gcloud auth print-identity-token)" -H "Content-Type:application/json" -d '{"data" : {"id" : "121123"}}' "https://asia-northeast1-my-project-name.cloudfunctions.net/MyFunction"
```

Now I want to call this function on my on-premise server, but don't want to install Cloud SDK which has 'gcloud' command (because gcloud auth require authenticate via browser). I copied above JSON file on local to this server and attempt to use [Google APIs Client Library for PHP](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client) to generate ID Token which is equivalent to command `gcloud auth print-identity-token`. I also referred to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20939305/16751216)

```php
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setAuthConfig('/path/to/json/file.json');
$client->useApplicationDefaultCredentials();
$client->addScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform');
$client->fetchAccessTokenWithAssertion();
$access_token = $client->getAccessToken();
var_dump($access_token);
```

If I have a valid token here I can call my Cloud Function, but when var_dump this $access_token, it printed out a weird string (which have so much 'dot' at the end) - looks like this:

```
ab29.c.Kp4BDgaiwej12ckskW0waSinDiMRcayZoBm5tp1lvc2813uEZjraVbU-4hKXxG2euqNS9wxRUa1aEKOH7n5w_VAhIUW9821Cy7Ca0c7_sXVDr_Nwouj8sVZR6gnjUFx51n8azUTX-RFMJBGE4_MrPT3hIMYYeBlIxy_IEUHF932xKPWR0ulf-wOa0o...............................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................
```

Of course this access_token cannot be used.

What is wrong with my steps above? If this way cannot be done, can you suggest a way that allow me to call Cloud Functions on on-premise server?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to make it work with the newest version of the API client, here's the code:

```
$client = new Google\Client();
$client->setAuthConfig('/path/to/private-key.json');
$client->useApplicationDefaultCredentials();
$client->setScopes($scope);
$client->setApplicationName($appName);
$access_token = $client->fetchAccessTokenWithAssertion();
$bearerToken = $access_token['id_token'];

// Now you can authenticate API calls by adding the Authorization header:
// "Authorization: Bearer $bearerToken"
```

Be sure to set the right path to the private key JSON file and replace scopes and Application name as required.

For using the Google Client API:

```
composer require google/apiclient:^2.15.0
```

Reference: https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client